# XAML bind BitmapImage ViewModel property

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher, bitmapimage

I have problem with update listbox from view model class. I use Caliburn Micro framework. My scenario is here:

I bind property of type bindableCollection on listbox:

**Code from view model:**

```
private BindableCollection<UserInfo> _friends;

public BindableCollection<UserInfo> Friends
{
    get { return _friends; }
    set
    {
        _friends= value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>Friends);
    }
}
```

In view model I create a fake service method which return new fresh data as List and with this data I update a property Friends which is bind on listbox.

I call fake service method in dispatcher timer tick event every 3 seconds.

```
 private static UserInfo FakeUser()
        {
            var user = new UserInfo
            {
                Age = "16",
                Emphasis = true,
                IdUser = "11542",
                IsBlocked = false,
                IsFriend = true,
                LocationInfo = new Location
                {
                    CityName = "TN",
                    IdCity = 123456,
                    IdRegion = 1246,
                    RegionName = "TN",
                },
                StatusInfo = new Status
                {
                    IdChat = 12,
                    IsLogged = true,
                    LastLogin = "153151",
                    IsChating = true,
                    RoomName = "Car",
                },
                ProjectStatusInfo = new ProjectStatus(),
                IsIamFriend = true,
                PlusInfo = new Plus(),
                ProfilePhoto = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://pokec.azet.sk/vanes90?i9=1f104a294997", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
            };    
            return user;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<UserInfo> GetFakeFriends()
        {
            var list = new List<UserInfo>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                list.Add(FakeUser());
            }

            return list;
        }

        private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_isExecuting)
                return;
            _isExecuting = true;
            new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
            {
                var freshFriends = GetFakeFriends();

                Execute.OnUIThread((System.Action)(() =>
                {
                    Friends.Clear();
                    foreach (var freshFriend in freshFriends)
                    {
                        Friends.Add(freshFriend);

                    }
                }));
            }).Start();

            _isExecuting = false;
        }

    }
```

If I don't apply any style on listbox, it works good.

**View:**

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="Friends"
             Grid.Row="2" 
             Margin="4,4,4,4">
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If I apply some style in which I bind property ProfilePhoto (typeof BitmapeImage) from UserInfo on listbox.

Style is here:

```
        <Style x:Key="friendsListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Name="RootLayout">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Margin="4,4,4,2" Source="{Binding Path=ProfilePhoto}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I get this error:

```
Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
```

If I make another style on listbox / listbox item, in which I bind only string or bool properties it works good.

I have problem only if bind bitmapImage property.

BitmapImage property is init as:

```
ProfilePhoto = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://pokec.azet.sk/vanes90?i9=1f104a294997", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
```

URI is url of picture or path to the file.

What is wrong? Thank for help and advice.

Style is good, it work only if I don't refresh data with method call in another thread.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you're creating the `BitmapImage` on any thread other than the UI thread, that would explain this issue. You can freeze the `BitmapImage` to ensure it is accessible from any thread:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(...);
bitmapImage.Freeze();
```

Comment: Great! How did you find this out?

Comment: Since `BitmapImage` inherits from `System.Windows.Freezable` - "A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads, while an unfrozen Freezable cannot." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx